# Editing dds mip maps?

Tags: textures, dds

What free software can do this?  There's the Nvidia plugin for photoshop but I don't have photoshop :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't as easy as just having it integrated into the editor (ala their Photoshop plugin), but check out nVidia's legacy tools, which include command line utilities for manipulating DDS files.

They are at http://developer.nvidia.com/legacy-texture-tools